# Mysql database connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, stored-procedures

I already have a MySQL db.

I would like to use WPF application in C#. I created the project and wrote the connection lines without errors.

How can I be sure that the connection goes okay? this code doens't returns errors but I would check the datas from the "query" cmd.

This is the connection code:

```
        string connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbamne;UID=root;PASSWORD=pass;";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name';", connection);

        connection.Open();
```

Comment: The real question is: What's the issue with the code you have?

Comment: the code doesn't returns errors but the db doesn't appear on the server Explorer Window so I would to check if this code is working or not.

Comment: I don't think the server will appear in that window unless you add it. Note that Visual Studio is an integrated development environment. It doesn't execute your code itself. It's like a text editor with a lot of useful features, right?

Comment: define "working" - does it have the effect you want? since you don't execute the command, it is hard to know. Note also that connections, commands, etc are all disposable - so you should be sure to dispose them (usually via `using`)

Comment: okay thank you to all. resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can check your connection using the method from [example at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#examples):

```cs
// ...

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
    Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
}
```

But if you directly want execute your command you should use method [`ExecuteReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteReader) at command (or it async analog) like  [MSDN recomended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#examples):

```cs
// ...

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'name';", connection);

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            /* This code shows just values from first column of your result table */
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
        }
    }
}
```